# Is it possible to force a number of levels for a factor?

Tags: r, types

I'm working with a data set containing city names and would like to use them as `factor` elements. My problem is, that some cities share the same name and are therefore interpreted as one level.

Illustration with four unique cities sharing three names:

```
# what I get

cities = c("a", "b", "a", "c")
> factor (cities)
[1] a b a c
Levels: a b c


# What I would like to have

> factor (cities)
[1] a b a c
Levels: 1 2 3 4 # or something similar
```

I tried forcing the number of factors using the `levels` parameter, but that removes the labels of the cities as well:

```
> factor (cities, levels=1:4)
[1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

Is there any way to solve this with factors or am I looking in the wrong corner here and `factor` isn't even the way to go with something like this?

Comment: The idea of factors is, that you have the same variable value for the same things. If you want to distinguish between the two entries of the cities, you can add a number to the second one, or identifiy them with rownames or a different column.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I want to avoid workarounds like adding numbers, etc.
Ideally, I'd just like some enum-like data structure in which entities and their labels are separated.

Comment: Not possible: in `factor` variable each unique character value is stored only once

Comment: You should have a unique name for each level. Or switch to IDs and have a mapping data.frame which you can use at the end of the analysis to format the variable properly.

Comment: `actor(make.unique(cities))`.

Comment: @snoram: While this would work, I'd like to avoid messing with the contents data.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an index to find out levels

```
cities = c("a", "b", "a", "c")
cities<-as.data.frame(cities)
cities$index<- seq.int(nrow(cities))

###data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ cities: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 1 3
 $ index : int  1 2 3 4
```

I hope this might be helpful

Comment: But this will create a new number for every new occurrence of 'a' right?

Comment: yes, if you want to make it based on city names that can also be done

Comment: Thank you, but the problem I see with this solution is that I want to find a more elegant way to enumerate the data rather than introduce another variable.